# in flutter vs code is not showing the error or hint how to solve this error

Tags: flutter

VS code is not showing the problems

not showing any od the hint or the syntax error in the flutter code

i have try to reinstall manytime vs code but it did not solved

enable error squiggle in the vs code and do many more thing to solve the error

Comment: Seems its a basic installation  mistake or conflicts, it would be better if you show the response of flutter doctor command to get the technical details

Comment: Try to Reset your VS code settings.

Comment: everytinng is done 4 or 5 time but it is the sdk problem

Answer (score 0):

i have tried so many more thing solve that but finally i have solve the error it happen because of the flutter sdk and solve the error by reinstall Flutter sdk and run the cmd Flutter clean and flutter pub get now error resolve

Comment: Please rewrite your answer, and add bullet points for steps you have done to achieve results.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Delete and uninsatll the Old Fluter Sdk
Step:2 Reinstall the New FLutter Sdk
Step:3 install the new extension for the dart and flutter in vscode
don't change any vscode setting error will be solved